# Java Using Arguments in a Complex Formula

Tags: java, formula, calc

I am new to Java, and I am reading a book on it now. The book does not give me the answer. I am using the following code:

```
package loanpayments;

public class LoanPayments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double years = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double P = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double r = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

        double R = r / 100;

        double A = P*(Math.E*Math.exp(R*years));

        System.out.println(A);
    }

}
```

I am testing the code with the following values:

- years = 3
- P = 2340
- r = 3.1

First I have to divide r by 100 to get a correct value (in this case it becomes 0.031). The new value of 0.031 becomes capitalized R. Then I use the formula to find A.

I am getting an incorrect output of ~6980.712, when the output should instead be ~2568.060.

I am thinking that I put in the formula wrong, it should be this:

P*e*^R(years)

In this case *e* is Euler's number (~2.71828)

If anyone could advise me on how to fix the formula, or some other mistake, I would much appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: As a side note: please conform to the Java coding conventions. Variables should never start with a capital letter. Only type names (classes, interfaces, enums) should start with a capital letter. Give variable meaningful names like `ratePercents` and `rate`, rather than `r` and `R`, and your code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not needed to multiply with another e because Math.exp() is already the exponential function.

Comment: I am not multiplying by another e, I don't think.

Comment: Oh, if I divide by A by e, it gives me the correct answer. Where I am multiplying by another e though?

Comment: @J.Doe:- Instead of `(Math.E*Math.exp(R*years)` try `(Math.exp(R*years)`

Comment: @RahulTripathi That fixed it, hmm, maybe multiplying by e is not necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe:- You are welcome. And do accept the answer if that helped you!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Done :D